# Getting user info from request to Cloud Function in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'd like to be able to get user information for a Cloud Function that gets called in Firebase. I have something like this, which is being called after the user signs into the app:

```
exports.myFunction = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => { ... }
```

And I need to get the uid of the signed-in user that made the request. Any advice or comments please?

Comment: This is one of those really obvious things that Firebase functions need to do that are incredibly poorly documented, so thanks for the question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Information about the user that makes the request is not automatically passed along with HTTPS functions calls.

You can either [pass the ID token along yourself and decode/verify it in your function](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/authorized-https-endpoint), or you can [use a *callable* HTTPS function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable), which passes the user information along automatically.

Answer (score 1):

To get the UID, you'll first need to pass the authToken on the request body.

```
// GET AUTH TOKEN ON THE CLIENT SIDE     
const authToken = await auth.currentUser.getIdToken()
```

Then, on the cloud function, you verify the token, which will return the UID.

```
// GET ID OF AUTHENTICATED USER
const { uid } = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(authToken)
```