# Firestore - Cloud Function - get Stripe user information with onRequest for Android

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

i'm trying to get the logged in user info from my Android app after an onRequest function is triggered when the User signs up for a [Stripe Standard Connect account](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts). The reason for this is because I'd like to add the user's Stripe accountId to the User's database in Firestore so I can have a way of tracking which user's are tied to which Stripe Connect Accounts.

I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52444812/getting-user-info-from-request-to-cloud-function-in-firebase) which sends me to [this link](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/authorized-https-endpoint/functions/index.js) however I'm not too sure on how to trigger it with my onRequest cloud function that I have.

Here is my cloud function:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const stripeToken = require('stripe')(functions.config().stripe.token);
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')();
const app = express();
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));

exports.stripeCreateOathResponseToken = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    let rawbody = req.rawBody;
    console.log("rawbody: " + rawbody); // <-- usually comes back with req.rawbody
    console.log("request.body.account: " + req.body.account); // <-- returns stripe account number
    return stripeToken.oauth.token({
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        code: req.query.code, //<-- works with onRequest ((req, res)
    }).then(function (response) {
        return res.redirect('http://MyWebSite.com/') //<-- works with onRequest
    })
.then(function(response){

        return addAccountToFirebase() //<-- shows error in firebase log but still executes
        // error: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

        return exports.app; // shows error: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

    })
.catch(error => {
        res.send(error)
    })
});

function addAccountToFirebase(user) {
    user = stripeToken.auth().customer.email
    return admin.firestore().collection('Users').doc(user.email).update({userStripeCusId: customer.id});
}
```

code from [firebase website](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/authorized-https-endpoint/functions/index.js)
**decode and verify userID token**

```
// Express middleware that validates Firebase ID Tokens passed in the Authorization HTTP header.
// The Firebase ID token needs to be passed as a Bearer token in the Authorization HTTP header like this:
// `Authorization: Bearer <Firebase ID Token>`.
// when decoded successfully, the ID Token content will be added as `req.user`.
const validateFirebaseIdToken = async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('Check if request is authorized with Firebase ID token');

  if ((!req.headers.authorization || !req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer ')) &&
      !(req.cookies && req.cookies.__session)) {
    console.error('No Firebase ID token was passed as a Bearer token in the Authorization header.',
        'Make sure you authorize your request by providing the following HTTP header:',
        'Authorization: Bearer <Firebase ID Token>',
        'or by passing a "__session" cookie.');
    res.status(403).send('Unauthorized');
    return;
  }

  let idToken;
  if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer ')) {
    console.log('Found "Authorization" header');
    // Read the ID Token from the Authorization header.
    idToken = req.headers.authorization.split('Bearer ')[1];
  } else if(req.cookies) {
    console.log('Found "__session" cookie');
    // Read the ID Token from cookie.
    idToken = req.cookies.__session;
  } else {
    // No cookie
    res.status(403).send('Unauthorized');
    return;
  }

  try {
    const decodedIdToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken);
    console.log('ID Token correctly decoded', decodedIdToken);
    req.user = decodedIdToken;
    console.log("req.user: " + req.user + " from exports.app")
    next();
    return;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error while verifying Firebase ID token:', error);
    res.status(403).send('Unauthorized');
    return;
  }
};

app.use(cors);
app.use(cookieParser);
app.use(validateFirebaseIdToken);

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Here is an example of how i'm able to add a Stripe customerID via an onCreate Call

```
// When a user is created, register them with Stripe
exports.createStripeCustomerOG = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => {
  const customer = await stripeToken.customers.create({email: user.email});
  return admin.firestore().collection('Users').doc(user.email).update({userStripeCusId: customer.id});
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are actually trying to do. Can you simplify your request sequence to come up with a minimal example and perhaps debug the issue?

This doesn't seem to be Stripe-related, but rather about sequence of events and request processing in your firebase functions. I suggest reframing to make it more clear for other readers.

Comment: Are you encountering any problem with the Stripe node client library itself?

Comment: @NolanH, Hi Nolan, The issue is retrieving the logged in userinfo with an onRequest call. I am not having any issues with the Stripe node client library. I think the other issue is figuring out how to use ExpressJs with the Android Studio Emulator

Comment: OK in that case I suggest editing your question to clarify the exact problem you're trying to solve. Removing the Stripe bits will contribute to tidying this, since it simply confuses the problem. Unfortunately I can't help with firebase userinfo/onRequest as that's outside my expertise.